# Combine base and dplyr: Force the creation of row numbers in a final object using as.matrix()

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse

In my case, I'd like to open my dataset (`RES_F`) and applied some `dplyr` function and using `as.matrix` for force the row number creation in my `X_train` final object:

```
library(dplyr)
RES_F<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/cnn_ds.csv",sep=",",h=T)
RES_train<-RES_F%>% group_by(status) %>% sample_n(1280)
X_train <- RES_train %>% select(-status) %>% as.matrix(nrow = length(RES_train[,2]), ncol = ncol(RES_train)-1, byrow = TRUE)
str(X_train)
# chr [1:2560, 1:5] "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : chr [1:5] "status" "NDVI" "SIPI" "RGI" ...
```

but, I don't have success in the substitution of `..$ : NULL` in `X_train`. My goal is:

```
#  ..$ : chr [1:2560] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#  ..$ : chr [1:5] "status" "NDVI" "SIPI" "RGI" ...
```

Please any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rownames(X_train) <- seq(1,nrow(X_train))
str(X_train)
# chr [1:2560, 1:5] "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" "attack" #"attack" "attack" "attack" ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:2560] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#  ..$ : chr [1:5] "status" "NDVI" "SIPI" "RGI" ...
```